# 3.3V to 5V logic converter

Tags: level-shifting

I'm looking to drive some NeoPixels off an 3.3V Arduino Nano. I've read that I need to use a logic shifter as the NeoPixels run off 5V. Adafruit recommends the chip 74AHCT125 but I want a surface mount chip.

Would the chip SN74HCT04DRG4 be a good alternative to this for logic shifter from 3 to 5v? Only difference I think its that its 6 circuits and no ability to disable circuits. I've read NeoPixels can be finicky with this so I want to make sure I have the correct part before getting it fab'd.

Also, as a sanity check, do I have this chip wired correctly? Here is my schematic:

[image]

Comment: If you like boutique chips, then ICs are the way to go. They do a lot for you. You can also use discretes for this. More general, less boutique. But it doesn't seem you want to go that direction. I'm a hobbyist and generally care more about approaches that are timeless (20 yrs minimum.) So I'll leave this to someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 74AHCT125 comes in both surface mount and through hole versions.

It says so right in the table on page 1 of the [DATASHEET](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ahct125.pdf).

The [SN74AHCT125**N**](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/texas-instruments/SN74AHCT125N/375798?s=N4IgjCBcoGwJxVAYygMwIYBsDOBTANCAPZQDaIALGGABxwDsIAuoQA4AuUIAyuwE4BLAHYBzEAF9xhAExkQ9CgEEAEgGEAKmGkBWZuKA) is the though hole version.

The surface mount versions are...

[SN74AHCT125**D**](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/texas-instruments/SN74AHCT125D/375813) (14-SOIC)
[SN74AHCT125**DGVR**](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/texas-instruments/SN74AHCT125DGVR/376206) (14-TVSOP)

Neither the 74AHCT125 or the SN74HCT04DRG4 are level translators.  But both could be used for that purpose.

The 74AHCT125 is a 4-channel non-inverting buffer with output enable.

The SN74HCT04DRG4 is a 6-channel inverter, which means that all the signals you put through it are going to be inverted.  So if you were relying on any pre-existing code libraries, they would have to be modified to make it work.

Comment: I have no need to disable the circuits, so I should tie the OE pin to ground, correct? Sorry I'm an SE guy trying to make a very simple board. I didn't catch that the one I picked was inverted so thank you!

Comment: I found a schematic confirming I can just tie it to ground. Thanks again for the help.